# Need previous keystore file

Tags: android, keystore, apk, android-keystore

I now finished upgrading android app... and trying to upload this upgraded version to google appstore.
But the problem is we don't have keystore file which was used for previous version.

And google app store doesn't permit me to upload apk cause SHA1 is different.

And apparently my customers don't have previously used keystore file.

What should I do?

Comment: If it's lost, there's no way. That's why it's a key. Are you sure you can't upload the app using a new **release** key? Users will get a message saying they will need to uninstall en reinstall the app though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've lost your Keystore file then there is no way that you can update the app in Play Store.